# how to pass array from html to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I try to pass array using jquery by ajax and back but my code not working well.
I all the time change it but it is not working.
please advise what to do.
I think my jquery code is ok but php code not replay.
thx.

html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allVals = { 
              'a': '1', 
              'b': '2',
              'c': '3' 
            }; 
            //$.each(allVals, function(key, value) { 
              //alert(key + ': ' + value); 
                //  });
            });
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     dataType: 'html',
     url: "test4.php",
     data: 'allVals=' + allVals,
         cache: false,
         success: function(data)
         {
            alert(data);
            $('#test').html(data);
            }
         });
</script>

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">##</div>
</body>
</html>
```

php code test4.php

```
<?php
    $allVals = $_POST['allVals'];
    if ($allVals != ""){
          foreach ($allVals as $key => $value) {
          echo ($key.' '.$value."<br />");
    }     }

?>
```

Comment: Do you get your success alert? Everything looks okay at first glimpse.

Comment: put the $.ajax code inside the ready function

Comment: try making a json-Array and send it

Comment: why do you have this `data: 'allVals=' + allVals,`

Comment: what should i write instad `data: 'allVals=' + allVals,` what you offer ?

Comment: What is the network console of your webdev console saying about your ajax-request? There must be either an error message or you success alert. Move the ajax-call into the document-ready function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also send an array to PHP from jQuery like this. In your example your sending an object:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    print_r($_POST['allVals']);
    /*
    Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 
    */
    die;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var myJavascriptArray = new Array('1', '2', '3');
    //or var myJavascriptArray=["1","2","3"]; 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "test.php",
        data: {'allVals[]=' : myJavascriptArray},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('#test').html(data);
        }
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the $.ajax-call outside the $(document).ready(...-scope. Move it inside!

I would do this part

```
data: 'allVals=' + allVals
```

like so:

```
data: allVals
```

And if you want to receive it as you do in php, change it to:

```
data: {"allVals": allVals}
```

Hope I got the syntax correctly.. ;)

Comment: I think `data: 'allVals=' + allVals,` equal to `data: {"allVals": allVals}`

Comment: yossi, you are doing the $.ajax-call outside the $(document).ready(...-scope move it inside!

Comment: You right I do mistake  $.ajax-call outside . but it still not working

Comment: yoss, `data: 'allVals=' + allVals` produces `[allVals] => [object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

```
data: 'allVals=' + allVals,
```

this is the culprit, what gets sent is `allvals[object Object]`

Comment: you are treating `object` allvals as a string with `'allVals=' + allVals` , thus allVals is convert into `[object Object]` so `'allVals=' + allVals` is `allvals[object Object]`

Comment: by changing `data: "allVals=" + allVals,` to `data: "allVals[]=" + allVals,` and changing `<?php
    $allVals = $_POST['allVals'];
    if ($allVals != ""){
          foreach ($allVals as $key => $value) {
          echo ($key.' '.$value."<br />");
    }     }

?>` I got success but the out put was `Array ( [0] => [object Object] )` It is mean that the array sent as empty ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a php array, I advise you to do like this :

`data: {allVals : allVals}`

The `$_POST['allVals']` will contains an array.

Otherwise, If you only need single parameters you have to do as follows :

```
var stringToSend = sep = "";
$.each(allVals, function(key, value) { 
    stringToSend += sep+key+"="+value;
    sep = "&";          
});
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
 dataType: 'html',
 url: "test4.php",
 data: stringToSend,
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better using jQuery [$.POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method:

```
var javascriptArray = new Array('a', 'b', 'c');

$.post('url_to_test4.php', {'allVals[]': javascriptArray }, function(data){
   // perform some action with the response data.
});
```

This will send to the PHP file an array named `allVals`, that will have the contents of your `javascriptArray`.